# Convergence to a finite random variable

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

The Martingale Convergence Theorem is typically stated that we have convergence to a 
(finite) random variable $X$ as $X_n \to X$ a.s when the conditions of the theorem are satisfied.

What is meant by a "finite" random variable? Would it be acceptable to replace the
phrase "finite random variable" with "bounded random variable"?

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "finite" usually means "almost surely finite", i.e. $|X(\omega)|<\infty$ for almost all $\omega \in \Omega$. Note that this does *not* imply the boundedness of $X$.

Comment: Thanks that makes a lot more sense. I will think about it from that perspective.